# How to Alter MySQL Query to Temporarily Change Column Name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, alter-table

I have the following SQL query:

> SELECT p.id, title, l.id, username  FROM photoTable p  JOIN userTable
>   l ON (l.id = p.iduser)  ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 50

I need to change the `p.id` to `p.IdPhoto` but the problem is that I only want this done temporarily within the call.  I have seen `ALTER TABLE` as an option, but I am a bit unsure of how I can do this without altering both `id` fields.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to change it just for the output or to re-use within the query?

Comment: I need to change for the output.

Comment: Then the solution posted by @brian-hoover should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
SELECT p.id as idPhoto, title, l.id, 
username 
FROM photoTable p 
JOIN userTable l ON (l.id = p.iduser) 
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: now it works!!!  Rather than `p.id` after the `ORDER BY` I just used `idPhoto` and it is good, thanks!  I'll award in 9 minutes :)